# Green tick to appear next to the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a small JS script that will like "highlight" the selected item, but I don't want to highlight it anymore, I want it to be selected with an image "like tick"

thanks

Comment: If you found an answer helpful, please put your own green check next to it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done entirely to CSS.

Simply use the `:before` pseudo class like so (would also work with `:after`):

```
.highlight:before{
    content : url(https://www.uaf.edu/bblearn/prod/browser-checker/checkmark.gif);
}

.highlight2:before{
    content: url(http://awriteword.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Red-Checkmark.png);
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csXyB/

---

you could also use the unicode checkmark with the same technique.

```
.highlight:before{
    content : '✓';
    color : green;
}

.highlight2:before{
    content: '✓';
    color:red;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gY8Ud/

Comment: Thank you. I made it after, and now its what I want

Comment: Opps @Johnツ you are right. Looking at the OP's example, after would have been a better choice. Still a reasonable answer though me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a checkmark character: ✓

To make it green you could assign a class to it:

```
// In your css
span.green {color:green;}

// In the HTML
<span class="green">&#x2713;</span>
```